# Importance of IDE/compiler version in embedded firmware development

Tags: linker, ide, versioning, firmware

I have heard that it is a good practice to stick to the same IDE version for a particular firmware development project across the team and always use the same version while development and fixes are done on it in future. One has to be careful in upgrading the IDE versions for the same project even if newer versions are available.

I was in a scenario where we were developing firmware using Atollic truestudio and using FreeRTOS. Although newer versions of both IDE and FreeRtos were available, we were advised to stick to the version which used for initial development.

What is the exact reason for doing so?
If we are upgrading to newer versions, what do we need to be careful about?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it doesn't matter, and sometimes it really does.

For example, I've worked on a part where we ROMed some portions of the C runtime library because every byte of program memory counted.

Once you've done that, you invite catastrophe if you change tools and either try to link to the old pieces of CRT or need to not use those anymore so you lose the blob of memory you are counting on for the application to fit.

Another case is moving from one set of revision of tools to another.  Keil 5.x to 6.x changed compilers and changed the linker descriptor files, and other linker symbol names, which would have incurred a large penalty on us because we use those symbols and layout for overlays, etc.  We'd have to go and touch a lot of our back end processing to form our firmware image correctly.

The IDE, though?  Meh.   Who uses the IDE project files, anyways? :)

(FWIW, changing Cmake versions on our current build environment could cause us pain, and we've been bit a few times by Python version changes).

Then there's the old adage:  if it ain't broke, then don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The short version of the answer is repeatability.
We all save the source code for our programs in a version control system and build from a release branch so that we always know exactly what we are shipping in our product, right? (Hopefully).

But the application source code is just one part of the puzzle.
The compiler and the support functions which come with and IDE or an RTOS are also programs.

Those programs are changed by their creators from time to time. There are improvements, sometimes bug fixes, etc.

That means that we are not using the exact same compiler or RTOS (for example) when we upgrade, and we cannot guarantee that they will produce exactly the same image, and exactly the same behavior, if we upgrade them.

There could be compiler improvements which optimize better, and therefore produce a slightly different image as output.

There could be changes in the RTOS behavior which could affect the timing of the system.

There could even be new bugs introduced while improvements are made an old bugs are fixed.

This means that if we change the underlying tools, we need to perform a complete verification to insure that the system we make has exactly the same behavior and performance characteristics as before.

I was literally discussing this with the Director of Firmware at our company yesterday.

We talked about how everyone has to continually choose between the stability of keeping the tools the same, and the potential benefits of upgrading the tools.

Since we are working on our next product, we have the opportunity to upgrade our tools before the product is released, and we plan to lock down not only the tools and run-time pieces, but even the operating system version used by our developers and our build machine.